# Sitecore Team Development Service (TDS) will not synchronise on new Windows 10 machine with VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sitecore, sitecore8.2, tds

I have setup a new development machine on Windows 10 with VS2017 and Sitecore 8.2 rev 170728 and am experiencing issues with TDS.

The TDS projects load, the Sitecore connector installs and I can see the _DEV folder and related files in the website folder but when I try and synchronise or perform the test from the TDS project properties I get a 503 error.

```
Exception The HTTP service located at http://sitecore/_DEV/TdsService.asmx is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later. (ServerTooBusyException):
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.Version(VersionRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.Version(VersionRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.Version()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.CheckClientVersion(TdsServiceSoapClient client, SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean retry)
Inner Exception Details:
Exception The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. (WebException):
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
Exception An error occured getting the TDS service version. Please review the Sitecore logs and/or windows events on the server to determine the problem. (ApplicationException):
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.GetTdsServiceSoapClient(String sitecoreWebUrl, String sitecoreAccessGuid, SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean checkVersion)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.GetTdsServiceSoapClient(SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean checkVersion)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.ToolWindows.SyncWithSitecoreToolWindow.SyncItemsWithSitecore(SitecoreProjectNode project, SitecoreItemNode syncRoot, Boolean sycnChildren)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreProjectPackage.ShowSitecoreSyncWindow(SitecoreProjectNode project, SitecoreItemNode selectedItem, Boolean syncChildren)
```

Everything is set correctly and the website is definitely up and running.

When I access the TdsService.asmx page directly I get an error trying to verify the version number

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Service is Locked ---> HedgehogDevelopment.Padlock.PadlockException: Service is Locked
   at HedgehogDevelopment.Padlock.Locking.CheckLock()
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.Version()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.Version()
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Sitecore connector, even tried different versions of TDS, different VS projects and even pointing TDS at a clean Sitecore installation.

I am not seeing any information in windows event logs, IIS logs or the Sitecore logs related to this error.

I have granted full control access to the website folder, the folder the code is in and the inetpub folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is caused by  the `TDSService.asmx` is locaked or inaccessible for your provided log error. please have try the following to troubleshoot and check if it helps.

1. Please check the `TDSService` is enabled and located at the config page at `xxx/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`.
2. Ensure your `App pool Identity` has `permission` to write the TDS service folder.
3. Try restart the `app pool` for the TDS.
4. Check the `TDS log` to exclude other potential error info.
5. Try to `reinstall` the TDS service and delete all remaining files firstly.
6. Also if all above is not working , suggest that raise a ticket for `Sitecore Support` for further assitance.